# Microsoft Edge Not Executing Javascript From CDN called From separate domain

Tags: javascript

There is a javascript file on a CDN which I will call application.js.

If I visit with edge a page on subdomain A that references this script everything loads and executives fine.

But if I then visit on edge again another subdomain B that references this script it loads but does not execute.

I can then go to any subdomain that reference said file and the same behavior of not executing will happen until I force a refresh and cache dump with crtl-F5.

The whole process starts over again. It works fine on which ever subdomain I visit first and then doesn't execute on any others.

Comment: I can not debug a problem that I don't see. To me this problem sounds too abstract and too specific to guess what may possibly be wrong.

Comment: It's not even running the javascript at all, no errors nothing. Non async load at the bottom of the file. I am not sure what more I can add given that...

Comment: for example, a few links so we can debug that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug with Edge Browser and CORS

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10703153/

I created a work around by having an inline script execute after the script that wasn't loading. If things are undefined, and the navigation didn't have on a reload I forced reload without the cache.